# customise core dump

Tags: segmentation-fault, coredump

can anybody tell me if there is a way we can force a segfault with certain specific information in it. Forcing a segfault can be done through abort(), call. But i need something
like abort(ptr), where ptr is a pointer that tells the actual memory where some corruption started.

thanks,
Kapil Upadhayay

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very unclear. Core dump contains a memory snapshot of your entire process, so it *already* contains the info you want it to contain.

If you want to make finding that info easier, you can introduce a global, e.g.

```
void *a_corrupt_ptr;  // global

void some_func() {
...

  if (the_pointer_has_been_corrupted(ptr)) {
    a_corrupt_ptr  = ptr;
    abort();
  }
```

and then examine `a_corrupt_ptr` in your debugger.

Or you can simply print the value before calling `abort()`.